# CSS width as percentage not displaying properly in IE7

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-views

I am trying to align my checkboxes on the following page into 3 columns. There are several different versions of this page and each one may have more or less checkboxes. The boxes align perfectly in Firefox and other browsers, but not in IE7. The CSS I am using is included below. Can someone help me figure out a fix for IE7? I am using the Better Exposed Filters for Drupal to produce the text boxes.

http://www.zambux.com/coupons/services

```
.bef-select-as-checkboxes .form-item {  
  width: 50%;  
  float: left;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using FF4 and it doesn't look right your page.

- First of all you have ".form-checkboxes" as 100px widh, change that on something wider or more flexible (otherwise always your elements will wrap badly)
- You cannot align things in 3 columns by using width:50% , because you are defining HALF of the space to be occupied by .form.item you would like to use 33% , but I suggest to do 30% and add 2% margin-right to keep a little bit of gap between the elements

I would do something like that as structure

```
<div class="container clearfix">
   <label for="input1">
     <input type="text" id="input1" />
     <span>my text</span>
   </label>
   <label for="input2">
     <input type="text" id="input2" />
     <span>my text</span>
   </label>
   <label for="input3">
     <input type="text" id="input3" />
     <span>my text</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

and add as CSS

```
#container label{width:30%; margin-right:2%; float:left;}
.clearfix:after { /*This is for clearing your floating elements*/
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```